# Angular component inside of router-outlet on child route will not fill available space

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular-routing, angular2-components

My application's root `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` will display the following component in a child Module when navigating to the '/child' route:

### child.component.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  template: `
    <div style="display:flex; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      <custom-sidebar-component></custom-sidebar-component>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>`
})
export class ChildComponent {
}
```

Now this component displays just fine and fills the entire screen as I expected. However, when I attempt to navigate to a child route of this module, say to '/child/home', I expect the following HTML to display in the child `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` seen in the component template above.

### child-home.component.html

```
<style>
  .parent-style {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .box-style {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>
<div class="parent-style">
  <div class="box-style">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box-style">Box 2</div>
</div>
```

But this time the contents of the router-outlet do not fill the available space as I was hoping. The only way I have been able to see the results I want is to open dev tools and edit the Angular generated _nghost attribute wrapping my component.  How can I get my component to fill available space?

### This is what I expect

[image: expected]

### This is what I actually get

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because rendered DOM was as below:

```
<app-child  _nghost-c1="">
<div _ngcontent-c1="" class="parent-style">
<div _ngcontent-c1="" class="box-style">Box 1</div>
<div _ngcontent-c1="" class="box-style">Box 2</div></div>
</app-child>
```

so the solution was quite simple, add some styles to the host element ,you can use `host:{'class':'foo'}` or directly add `host:{'style':'width:100%'}` in the `@Component{}` of your ChildComponent

Comment: So simple, that did actually fix my problem.  I was not familiar with styling shadow dom elements, thanks for the info! Today I learned.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, are there any other solutions to this rather than style the host element in each of the child elements?